# How to use a dictionary to output a dictionary key using an asked input

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm fairly new to coding so I don't know much of the terminology but I am trying to use this dictionary. I am curious why one version works but not the other. The first code outputs None when I input the first dictionary Key (379048997) but the second outputs the actual value

```
PeptideLibrary = {
    379048997:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_Phe'],
    379050201:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_3OHPhe'],
    379047420:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Sar','Prop','D_Phe']
}
RFID = input( "What is your RFID? : ")
print(PeptideLibrary.get(RFID))

#Input: 379048997
#Output: None

PeptideLibrary = {
    379048997:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_Phe'],
    379050201:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_3OHPhe'],
    379047420:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Sar','Prop','D_Phe']
}

print(PeptideLibrary.get(379048997))

#Output:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_Phe']
```

First code, outputs None when I input 379048997
Second code, outputs ['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_Phe'] when explicitly input 379048997 to .get() function

Comment: `dict` is a `key:value` pair.  You have supplied a `list` as the `value` of the `key` 379048997, so the `value` ['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_Phe'] was returned.

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary keys are `int` but `input` returns a `str` hence you need to cast `RFID`:

```
print(PeptideLibrary.get(int(RFID)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary keys are integers. `input()` returns a string. You need to convert the string to an integer.

```
PeptideLibrary = {
    379048997:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_Phe'],
    379050201:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_3OHPhe'],
    379047420:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Sar','Prop','D_Phe']
}
RFID = int(input( "What is your RFID? : "))
print(PeptideLibrary.get(RFID))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
RFID = int(input("What is your RFID? : ")
```

input returns a string and 379048997 is not the same as "379048997".

Answer (score 1):

Because input() function returns string, and your dictionary has numbers as keys
[image]

just convert RFID variable to int after input:

```
PeptideLibrary = {
    379048997:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_Phe'],
    379050201:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Benz','Prop','D_3OHPhe'],
    379047420:['D_Leu','Ile','Leu','Sar','Prop','D_Phe']
}
RFID = input( "What is your RFID? : ")
RFID = int(RFID)
print(PeptideLibrary.get(RFID))
```